# Tensorflow, getting index of non-zero values for every row in a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I want to get the index of the values that are not zero for every row in my matrix. I've tried with tf.where but the output is not like I expecteded.

My code now is:

```
b = tf.constant([[1,0,0,0,0],
                 [1,0,1,0,1]],dtype=tf.float32)
zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
where = tf.not_equal(b, zero)
indices = tf.where(where)
```

And indices output is:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=136, shape=(4, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4]])>
```

But I would like the output to be:

```
[[0],
 [0,2,4]]
```

Where I have a list with the indexes per row.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that result is not a proper tensor, because each row does not have the same number of columns. If you want something like that, you can either have that result "padded" to make all rows the same lengths (e.g. padding with -1, which is an invalid value, or having another vector indicating the number of valid indices on each row), or use a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) (a bit more complicated to work with but actually would represent what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be a proper tensor, since dimensions are not uniform. If you are okay with using a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors) you can do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    b = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],dtype=tf.float32)
    num_rows = tf.shape(b)[0]
    zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    where = tf.not_equal(b, zero)
    indices = tf.where(where)
    s = tf.ragged.segment_ids_to_row_splits(indices[:, 0], num_rows)
    row_start = s[:-1]
    elem_per_row = s[1:] - row_start
    idx = tf.expand_dims(row_start, 1) + tf.ragged.range(elem_per_row)
    result = tf.gather(indices[:, 1], idx)
    print(sess.run(result))
    # <tf.RaggedTensorValue [[0], [0, 2, 4]]>
```

EDIT: If you don't want to or cannot use ragged tensors, here is an alternative. You can produce a tensor padded with "invalid" values. You can either have for example -1 in those invalid values, or just have a 1D tensor that tells you how many valid values you have on each row:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    b = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],dtype=tf.float32)
    num_rows = tf.shape(b)[0]
    zero = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    where = tf.not_equal(b, zero)
    indices = tf.where(where)
    num_indices = tf.shape(indices)[0]
    elem_per_row = tf.bincount(tf.cast(indices[:, 0], tf.int32), minlength=num_rows)
    row_start = tf.concat([[0], tf.cumsum(elem_per_row[:-1])], axis=0)
    max_elem_per_row = tf.reduce_max(elem_per_row)
    r = tf.range(max_elem_per_row)
    idx = tf.expand_dims(row_start, 1) + r
    idx = tf.minimum(idx, num_indices - 1)
    result = tf.gather(indices[:, 1], idx)
    # Optional: replace invalid elements with -1
    result = tf.where(tf.expand_dims(elem_per_row, 1) > r, result, -tf.ones_like(result))
    print(sess.run(result))
    # [[ 0 -1 -1]
    #  [ 0  2  4]]
    print(sess.run(elem_per_row))
    # [1 3]
```